# How to get associated records in polymorphic scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a scenario like

```
class Manager
  has_many :employees
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactable
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :manager
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactable
end

class Transaction
  belongs_to :transactable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Any better way to get all the transactions that are made by `Manager` or/and his `employees`? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Transaction

  def self.belonging_transactions(manager)
    where(
      "(transactable_type = 'Manager' AND transactable_id = ?) OR (transactable_type = 'Employee' AND transactable_id IN ?)",
      manager.id,
      manager.employees.ids
    )
  end

end
```

You can get all manager & its employees transaction by,

```
Transaction.belonging_transactions(manager) # here manager is Manager class object
```

Result could be obtained by adding (using `+`) two `where` queries but it will be `Array` and not a `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: in where scope there should be `IN` operator. `(transactable_type = 'Employee' AND transactable_id IN ?)`

Answer (score -1):

You can define custom scope for `Transaction`s that are made by `Manager` and his `employees`:

```rb
class Transaction
  scope :belonging_transactions, ->(manager) do
    where(transactable_type: "Manager", transactable_id: manager.id)
      .or(transactable_type: "Employee", transactable_id: manager.employees.ids)
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can define a class method, that does the same:

```rb
class Transaction

  def self.belonging_transactions(manager)
    where(transactable_type: "Manager", transactable_id: manager.id)
      .or(transactable_type: "Employee", transactable_id: manager.employees.ids)
  end

end
```

Comment: This solution won't give correct result because you are checking only `transactable_id` and there may be a case where manager_id and one of his employee_id will be same(i.e, both are different table). So you have to also check `transactable_type` in where scope.

Comment: @RakeshPatidar - Yep, you're right - Fixed. I hope it helps.